# Windows with mapped drive -- _stat() fails to detect existence of the file

Tags: windows, visual-c++, path, stat

**Summary:** The `_stat()` function says that there is not an existing file when the drive letter is mapped to UNC path.

**Details:** On Windows system, there is the UNC path like

```
\\computer\sharename\disk_M\the_subdir\file.txt
```

and it is mapped this way:

```
net use M: \\computer\sharename\disk_M
```

Then the `file.txt` can be accessed as `M:\the_subdir\file.txt`, and I can really see its content in an editor.

The problem is that I need to test for the file existence in my program. I do use the following function:

```
bool isfile(const std::string & path)
{
    struct _stat stat;

    if (_stat(path.c_str(), &stat))
        return false;                   // the call returns -1 with errno ENOENT

    return (stat.st_mode & _S_IFREG) != 0;
}
```

When debugging, I have found that the `_stat` calls the `FindFirstFile` function:

```
    /* Call Find Match File */
    findhandle = FindFirstFile((_TSCHAR *)name, &findbuf);
    if ( findhandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        _TSCHAR * pBuf = NULL;
```

... and it fails to find the file exactly here.

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong? How can I enhance the detection of the existence of a file? (The code runs in the environment where the drive mapping was made by the local administrator, and I cannot change the configuration.)

Comment: Can you see the file `m:\the_subdir\file.txt` from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I can normally see it via `cmd`, I can find it also via the Windows Explorer, via Total Commander, and I can launch an editor to see the file content.

Comment: Well, I'm sure it is not actually called "file.txt".  Give the *exact* name of the file.  When you use std::string then it gets to be very important what code page your program is running in and whether or not the file contains non-ASCII characters.  So mention this as well.  If you don't know then tells us what country you live in.

Comment: You are right. The name is `m:\Market\APSm32\start.cfg`. The computer is actually my computer, and I can reach the same file via a path starting with `D:` (local disk path). Then the file is detected without problem. The mapping makes the difference. I am aware of the problems you touched. However, I have new finding. The problem was observed when using Visual C++ 2005. The same code seems to work correctly in the same situation when VC++ 2010 is used. If you find more details about the fact, please write is as the comment. Then the bounty will be yours :) (I am also trying.)

Comment: May be the share security settings prevents you from a accesing that file in your program. You could try to test PathFileExists (SHLWAPI) and if it fails call GetLastError() to get more details.

Comment: What about [GetFileAttributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/23/5612082.aspx) ?

Comment: @bkausbk: The `PathFileExists` returns FALSE and the `GetLastError` returns ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND (value 3).

Comment: @ixe013: The `GetFileAttributes` returns INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES, and the `GetLastError` returns ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND (value 3).

Comment: Only to be sure, you didn't forgot to escape backslahes? It should be isfile("M:\\the_subdir\\file.txt"). And you really mapped \\computer\sharename\disk_M and not \\computer\sharename\disk_M\the_subdir?

Comment: @bkausbk: No, I did not forget. The path is extracted from the command line arguments. It works when not so complicated mapping is used. To emphasize it again, it seems the problem is present only when Visual C++ 2005 is used. The VC++ 2010 works fine.

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if char* or wchar_t* is used instead of std::string? If not using compiler specific methods/classes like CRT/STL there should be no difference between VC++ 2005 and VC++ 2010.